# Repeating regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a log file which i want to parse. It is about getting the Values between the square brackets and after the "OK:" using regex.
The Problem is i do not know how many times the pattern is occuring and i can not say how long each code is. So i can only relay on the fact that it is surrounded by "[OK:" and "]".

So far i tried to use this pattern here as regex:

```
String ok_pattern = "(.*itId=<)(.{1,10})(>.*)(\\[OK:)(.{4,27})(].*)";
Pattern p_ok = Pattern.compile(ok_pattern);

String testString = "RANDOMTEXT itId=<1232> Code < [OK:AZ1000105]  [OK:10000006] [OK:F1000000007] > RANDOMTEXT";

Matcher m = p_ok.matcher(testString);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(5));
}
```

But this only works for the case when there is only one "[OK:...]".
I played around with using a "*" and "+" after the 5th group but i could not succeed.
How do i do this repetetive and still capture all results?

My goal is to extract the itemId and the (char-)number combination after the "OK:" using regex. So in this example I want to get "1232"(ItemID) and "AZ1000105", "10000006", "F1000000007".

I am thankful for every help!

Comment: You could use a capturing group `\[OK:([A-Z0-9]+)\]` https://regex101.com/r/rty1K8/1

Comment: Do you want to capture the id too ?

Comment: @FILE_q Do you mean  like this? https://regex101.com/r/rty1K8/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic setup is correct, but your pattern is somewhat off from ideal.  Try using the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=\[OK:)[^\]]+|(?<=itId=<)[^>]+
```

This still uses a lookbehind, but it only asserts that what precedes is `[OK:`.  Then, it matches, without even using a capture group, any amount of characters which are *not* a closing square bracket.  This corresponds to the content you are trying to find.  The portion to the right of the alternation matches `itId` values.

```
String ok_pattern = "(?<=\\[OK:)[^\\]]+|(?<=itId=<)[^>]+";
Pattern p_ok = Pattern.compile(ok_pattern);
String testString = "RANDOMTEXT itId=<1232> Code < [OK:AZ1000105]  [OK:10000006] [OK:F1000000007] > RANDOMTEXT";

Matcher m = p_ok.matcher(testString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}

1232
AZ1000105
10000006
F1000000007
```

Comment: following that approach helped me to actually get the codes. but then i could not add the "(.*ItemId=<)" in front of it anymore. how can i combine getting the one ItemId before and then the OK-codes?

Comment: @FILO_q Not sure what more I can say here; my code works with your sample input.  If you have other input cases, then edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: ok so summarized: i want to get the itId and then afterwards the unknown number of OK: codes.

Comment: @FILO_q I edited my question to also capture Id's using an alternation.  Both Ids and codes get printed, so hopefully the output would be clear.

Comment: that is very close, but it returns now "itId=<1232>" instead of only "1232". If you can tell me how to fix it im done!

Comment: What output do you want to see?  Do you want to see just a 4 digit number for the item Id, or something else?

Comment: Amazing danke Tim! Solved

Comment: Bitte schoen Filo, güten nacht.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the digits in `itId=<1232>` followed by subsequent captures of what is after `OK:` in that order , you could make use of the `\G` anchor to assert the position at the end of the previous match.

Match the `itId` digits in the first capturing group and the value of `OK:` in the second capturing group:

```
itId=<(\d+)> Code < |\G(?!^)\[OK:([A-Z0-9]+)\]\s*
```

In Java:

```
String ok_pattern = "itId=<(\\d+)> Code < |\\G(?!^)\\[OK:([A-Z0-9]+)\\]\\s*";
```

**Explanation**

- `itId=<(\d+)> Code <` Match the first part and capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `|` Or
- `\G(?!^)` End of the previous match, not at the start
- `\[OK:([A-Z0-9]+)\]\s*` Match `[OK:`, then capture your value in group 2 and match `]` followed by 0+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qLS4sK/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/QgveK8)

Note that if you want to match more than `([A-Z0-9]+)` you could also use a negated character class to match not a square bracket `([^]]+)`

For example, you might check for the existence of the groups:

```
String ok_pattern = "itId=<(\\d+)> Code < |\\G(?!^)\\[OK:([^]]+)\\]\\s*";
Pattern p_ok = Pattern.compile(ok_pattern);
String testString = "RANDOMTEXT itId=<1232> Code < [OK:AZ1000105]  [OK:10000006] [OK:F1000000007] > RANDOMTEXT";
Matcher m = p_ok.matcher(testString);

while(m.find()) {
    if (null != m.group(1)) {
        System.out.println("itId: " + m.group(1));  
    }
    if (null != m.group(2)) {
        System.out.println("Ok code: " + m.group(2));   
    }   
}
```

Comment: how can i actually access the values then?
if i try to use:
```
Matcher m = p_ok.matcher(testString);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(5));
}
```
I dont get any results.

Comment: Did you check the demo link? For exmple https://ideone.com/QgveK8 You can check for the existence of the different groups.

Comment: @FILO_q I have added and example and perhaps test it here https://rextester.com/ZTEMBP76897

Comment: Thank you very much. You and Tim Biegeleisen solved it at the same time... thanks for your help!